# svn: QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Accidentally when I try to update anything on my svn either on terminal or intellij I get this massage

> QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
>   QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to "Clear Auth Cache" from Intellij, Open Intellij and do the following

1. File --> Settings
2. Search about "Version Control" --> "Subversion".
3. Click on "Clear Auth Cache" button.
4. Press OK.
5. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: This problem repeats daily and sometimes several times a day even after clearing the auth cache.  Any other solutions that aren't so laborious?

Comment: What is the version of Intellij that you used?

Comment: AndroidStudio 3.1.4.  It seems to get back into the bad state after I use svn on the command line.

Comment: I guess using svn from different ways (permissions issue to access ~/.subversion) could cause such problems, maybe the AndroidStudio has a different permission than you have in the command line.

Comment: I don't know how it could have different permissions.  I suspect the problem is with kwallet and AndroidStudio not playing nice with each other.  See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128155 .

Answer (score 1):

Remove kdesvn if you're using it. Afterwords clear cache (`rm -rf ~/.subversion` by default)

Answer (score 0):

My error occurred in Pycharm and theses steps work for me:

1. Remove kdesvn (`sudo apt purge kdesvn`)
2. Dell svn cache folder ~/.subversion (`rm -r ~/.subversion`)
3. Config Pycharm > Subversion > Enable interactive mode:

[image]

Versions:

- Kubuntu 18.04
- KDE Plasma 5.12.7
- KDE Framework 5.44.0
- Qt Version: 5.9.5
- Kernel: 4.15.0-46-generic